# How to move tasks from GoTasks app into another phone

Tags: data-transfer, app-data

I've just changed phone.

Using [Samsung smart switch](http://www.samsung.com/ca_fr/support/smartswitch/) app, I was able to transfer all my stuff from my old phone to the new one. Everything has been transferred with this app, except tasks stored within GoTasks app. I know this application can synchronize with google account, but back in the days, I didn't care about that and just used local task saved directly into my phone for the convenience of it.

Overtime, I've put a lot a task with a lot of detail there so rewriting them in the new phone isn't really an option.

So [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143790/139093), it would seem Titanium Backup could rescue me. With it, I could backup data of the app from my old phone and restore the backup into my new phone. The problem is that this application need to phone to be rooted. Apparently, my old phone was and I wasn't even aware of it. My new phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5 running android 6.0.1 and I was unable to root it so far using "kingRoot, kingo root" and others. (sad) Yet, there is probably other thing to try to root it, but here the thing, rooting is almost illegal and void warranty. I might not care about this, but I wonder if I really need to get down that path to get my TasksGo tasks   transferred into my new phone.

Is there a better way to transfer the tasks of GoTasks from my old phone to my new phone? I would love something as easy as copy pasting a file from my old phone to my new phone, but sadly it doesn't seem that simple... There is no tasks saved in gotasks app of the new phone.

My old phone is a Samsung Galaxy3 running android 4.1 if that could help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was able to use google synchronization and a reasonable amount of manual work to get the tasks on the new phone.

Here is what I did.
Step 1 through 5 are on the old phone, after that they are on the new phone.

#### Step1

Rename a list of tasks in TasksGo to add "local" or "old" at the end.

#### Step2

Create a new task list with the original name of the list renamed at Step1. Here, you need to link this new list to your google account.

#### Step3

Put the new list below the old one. Then, from the last to the first one, start drag and dropping all task from the old list into the list.

#### Step4

Delete the now empty old task list and repeat step 1 to 4 until there isn't any local task list anymore.

#### Step5

Hit synchronise in the app's menu. This wasn't enough for me because automatic sychronisation is off on my old phone. I had to go into Android:"Setting\account" to mannually hit synchronise on GoTasks's data there. If you don't have a google account linked to your phone, this is also the place to add it.

#### Step6

On the new phone, open goTask and hit synchronize and to import all the good stuff. Your might need to do the manual sych. in the phone's setting like for step5 if automatic synch is off.

I had many list of tasks that each had plenty of tasks, so I had to find a way. With the amount of data I had, it took me an hour, but it should be much less than that if your usage of this app is lightlier than mine.

Author of this application is Evgeny Shurakov. Since the app was renamed, searching for the author is easier to find back this application now a day.